# Sci-fi movie, likely black and white, includes a robot/human losing rivets and bolts (as he was injured)

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a long shot but still giving it a try. All I remember about this movie which I saw as a child is that there's was an alien robot who did not want to return to the spaceship and drove away with a woman in a car. When the robot left the car, there were some rivets and bolts left on the car seat as the robot was either hurt or something as he was losing its parts.

Edited to add:
- Movie is most likely black and white (watched it on a B/W TV as a child in 80's)
- Based on production as I can remember, it must be 50's or 60's movie
- Sadly I can only vividly remember that particular scene, a human looking robot was shot and was not actually bleeding but was losing bolts, a woman was driving him in a car to a sea-shoreline, to catch a space ship? Once he stood up from the car seat, few bolts were left on the seat

Comment: Live-action? Animated? When were you a child? We have some prompts at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to help you elicit more details that you can edit into your question.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already; but maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Anything, however minor it may seem, helps. Cheers :)

Comment: What kind of robot? Classic tin can with arms? Human-ish with some metal bits? What was the rest of the movie about? Were the robot and women main characters?

Comment: Added a few comments. Will check all the guidelines now. Thank you all for your comments, I really appreciate it!

Comment: DJClayworth Human looking robot with no particular marks on the body, I think he/it was wearing a trench coat. And yes, I believe she and him were main characters in the movie.